# React infinite/max-level comment for each news post

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops

I have a News feature where user can post their status. However, so far, I cannot make it display all comments of the news as my current solution only allows two-level only. Here are my codes:

**News.js (for all)**

```
function News() {

    const {userId, setUserId} = useContext(UserContext);
    const {type, isUserType} = useContext(UserTypeContext);

    const [newsList, setNewsList] = useState([]);

    const rootNews = newsList.filter(
        (newList) => newList.reply_of === null
    );

    const getReplies = commentId => {
        return newsList.filter(newList => newList.reply_of === commentId);
    }


    useEffect(()=>{
        
        Axios.get('http://localhost:3001/news',{  
        })
        .then((response) => {
            if(response.data.length > 0){

                setNewsList(response.data);
            
            }

        })

    },[]);

return (
    <div className = "news p-5">
        <h3 className="news-title">News</h3>
        <div className = "comments-container">
            {rootNews.map((rootNew) => (
                <div>
                    <Comment key={rootNew.news_id} 
                    comment={rootNew}
                    replies={getReplies(rootNew.news_id)}/>
                </div>
            ))}
        </div>
</div>
 )
}
```

**Comment.js (for rendering the comments and replies)**

```
function Comment({comment, replies}) {
  return (
    <div className="comment">
        <div className="comment-image-container">
            <img src = "/user-icon.png" />
        </div>
        <div className="comment-right-part">
            <div className="comment-content">
                <div className="comment-author">
                    {comment.user_name}
                </div>
                <div>{comment.day}, {moment(comment.date).format('DD-MM-YYYY')} at {comment.time}</div>
            </div>
            <div className="comment-text">{comment.news_title}</div>
            {replies.length > 0 && (
                <div className="replies">
                    {replies.map(reply => (
                        <Comment comment={reply} key={reply.news_id} replies={[]}/>
                    ))}
                </div>
            )}
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

This is an example on how the comment structure would look like:

```
Comment 1
 Reply 1.1
  Reply 1.1.1
   Reply 1.1.1.1
 Reply 1.2
Comment 2
```

An idea on how I could render infinite replies, or possibly set the maximum level of replies allowed? Thank you

Comment: Why are you providing empty array in the second level?

Comment: @Prana because I can't render the whole page if I did not provide the empty array

Comment: @red17 can you provide example data for what a deeply nested comments structure might look like?

Comment: @DerekPollard I updated my question, hope it answers your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need a little change to the `Comment` component to recursively render the already nested data structure:

```js
function Comment({ comment, newsList }) {
  
  const replies = newsList.filter((newList) => newList.reply_of === comment.news_id);

  return (
    <div className="comment">
      <div className="comment-image-container">
        <img src="/user-icon.png" />
      </div>
      <div className="comment-right-part">
        <div className="comment-content">
          <div className="comment-author">{comment.user_name}</div>
          <div>
            {comment.day}, {moment(comment.date).format("DD-MM-YYYY")} at{" "}
            {comment.time}
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="comment-text">{comment.news_title}</div>
        {replies.length > 0 && (
          <div className="replies">
            {replies.map((reply) => (
              <Comment key={reply.news_id} comment={reply} newsList={newsList} />
            ))}
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Basically, you just move the code that gets the direct replies to a comment into the `Comment` component.

When you render the root `Comment` component, all direct replies to the root comment will be identified and will cause the rendering of nested `Comment` components, which will in turn identify the replies to the reply, render a nested `Comment` component and so on.

Comment: I first got the error ```TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'filter')``` so I change it to ```var replies``` and added an ```if(newsList)```.  Then another error occured: ```TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')```.

Comment: @red17 In `News`, you have to render `Comment` like this: `<Comment key={rootNew.news_id} comment={rootNew} newsList={newsList} />`. This ensures `newsList` is always an array so you don't get those TypeErrors